# Starting of cover letter for academic jobs

Tags: application-cover-letter

I have sent an academic job application with a cover letter starting "Dear Madam or Sir,..." and I've just realised that the correct form is instead "Dear Search Committee Chair,...". Have I made a huge mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not. I doubt anyone is going to catch it and, if they do, they probably won't care.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't even made a small mistake.  The salutation you used is just fine.  I actually like it better than the other idea you find (Search Committee Chair).